# How to get a vector from its length and angle

Tags: vectors

How can I get the vector when I know its length and angle?

E.g. `length = 3` and `angle = 40°`.

Comment: What is the angle of a vector?

Comment: ? http://people.sinclair.edu/nickreeder/eet155/PageArt/vector.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "angle of the vector" you mean the angle between the vector and the positive side of the $\;x$-axis and counterclockwise, which is the usual agreement, then

$$x=3\cos40^\circ\;,\;\;y=3\sin40^\circ\;,\;\;\text{and the vector is then}\;\;\binom xy$$

Comment: I assume this works for radians too?

Answer (score 2):

In polar coordinates, you already do!

Otherwise draw a picture with horizontal leg of length $x$ and vertical leg of length $y$, take the sine and cosine of the angle and solve for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I have expressed myself wrong: how can I convert this information to this notation: ( 3 2 ) (don't know how to make the numbers vertical in a comment)

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are what you are looking for - the $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

Comment: Is `x` calculated by `sin` or `cos`?

Comment: You see your picture above. Drop a vertical from the 'tip". Now the length of this vertical is the $y$-coordinate. The length of the vector is three as you said. Now, how do you find the sine if an angle?